# React-spring - Animated div removes onclick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-spring

I'm facing problem with my `onClick` function which is on **a** element. Without React-spring animations it works perfectly. But since I've added animations to it, function is not working. No errors in console, and I really can't find any problems like this on google. Have you encountered this type of problem?

**Declaring an animation**

```
import {useTransition, animated} from 'react-spring';

const gameOptionsTransitions = useTransition(showGameOptions, null, {
 from: { opacity: 0, transform:'translateY(200px)' },
 enter: { opacity: 1, transform:'translateY(0)' },
 leave: { opacity: 0, transform:'translateY(200px)'}
});
```

**In return**

```
{gameOptionsTransitions.map(({ item, key, props }) =>
      item && 
          <animated.div key={key} style={props}>
              <Link to="/play">
                  <a className="playerVsComputer-btn" onClick={props.playPlayerVsComputer}>Player vs. Computer</a>
              </Link>
                
              <Link to="/play">
                  <a className="playerVsComputer-btn" onClick={props.playPlayerVsPlayer}>Player vs. Player</a>
              </Link>

              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                  <input type="text" ref={sizeOfBoard} onChange={removeHighlightInput} autoFocus />
              </form>
          </animated.div>
  )};
```

As you can see, both of **a** elements are wrapped in **Link** element. So after click, you will be redirected to that path but also function should be fired. This function is sent to this component from App.js as a prop. I've tried to move whole **`onClick={props.playPlayerVsComputer}`** from **a** element to **Link** but nothing changes.

**Sent function**

```
  function playPlayerVsPlayer(){
    setPlayerVsPlayer({
      AI:false,
      AImove:false
    });

    setDimensions({
      rows:"3",
      columns:"3"
    })

    generateMatrix(3,3);
  }
```

This function sets dimensions state and then create matrix according to these dimensions. Then **generateMatrix** function fires another function, which renders  rows x columns table to App. But it's not that important because there will be problem with that animated div, not with these functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed animated div like this, so **Link** element don't have any other elements inside, also **classNames** moved to **Link** element.

```
{gameOptionsTransitions.map(({ item, key, props }) =>
    item && 
        <animated.div key={key} style={props}>
            <Link to="/play" className="setGameMode-btn" onClick={playPlayerVsComputer}>
                Player vs. Computer
            </Link>
    
            <Link to="/play" className="setGameMode-btn" onClick={playPlayerVsPlayer}>
                Player vs. Player
            </Link>

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" ref={sizeOfBoard} onChange={removeHighlightInput} autoFocus />
            </form>
        </animated.div>
)};
```

For onClick events I have created two new functions which are calling these functions from App.js as a props.

```
//Fire animations sent as a props
function playPlayerVsComputer(){
    props.playPlayerVsComputer();
}

function playPlayerVsPlayer(){
    props.playPlayerVsPlayer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a react spring transition which have its own `props` ,

All you have to do just rename the `props` => to other name (annimationProps by example ) in order to not confuse the props passed to your component by the App file

as below :

```
{gameOptionsTransitions.map(({ item, key, annimationProps }) =>
      item && 
          <animated.div key={key} style={annimationProps}>
              <Link to="/play">
                  <a className="playerVsComputer-btn" onClick={props.playPlayerVsComputer}>Player vs. Computer</a>
              </Link>
                
              <Link to="/play">
                  <a className="playerVsComputer-btn" onClick={props.playPlayerVsPlayer}>Player vs. Player</a>
              </Link>

              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                  <input type="text" ref={sizeOfBoard} onChange={removeHighlightInput} autoFocus />
              </form>
          </animated.div>
)};
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! You approach did fix the function, now it's working as It is supposed to, but now animation doesn't work.. I've fixed it with this approach. check answer

Comment: I have posted it now

Comment: Do you have any experience with transitioning between routes? @SpringerF

Comment: @Pinncik , nop not realy sorry